# ViewGroupManager vs SimpleViewManager

Tags: react-native, native

In react-native what are the deff* between ViewGroupManager and SimpleViewManager ?

Thanks.

Comment: I'd LOVE to know that as well.
It seems that the native realms of react-native are SOO undocumented.

Did you finally figure that out?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the answer to that is exactly the same as this:

[Difference between View and ViewGroup in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27352476/difference-between-view-and-viewgroup-in-android)

`SimpleViewManager` extends [View](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/uimanager/SimpleViewManager.java#L22)

and

`ViewGroupManager` extends [ViewGroup](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/uimanager/ViewGroupManager.java#L27)

I copy the following image from [the above answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27352476/difference-between-view-and-viewgroup-in-android) that explains their difference:

[image]

So to simplify things, it looks like whenever you have a very similar native UI component then you'd wanna use a `SimpleViewManager`, but if you want to have children within parents then you need to use a `ViewGroupManager`.